# WebView in android studio

Tags: android, webview

I am new to Android Programming and recently I want to develop an android web app. I found out that I need MVVM design architecture, retrofit, API, Json things to create a web app. But I found out another way and that is "WebView".And I also found that "WebView" work pretty well and also pretty easy to create a Web app.

what is the real difference between WebView and the first way i mentioned?

Comment: Webview is the android element to load webpages which does not actually help you develop interactive web app.

Comment: @learner Ok thz bro.